# Using an 'if' statement in data.frame using dplyr

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame like so

```
Letter Number Type        Ratio
A        10    Plant        6        
A        11    Person       65
B        9     Fungus       32
B        10    Bacteria     344
C        13    Bacteria     2
C        15    Bacteria     3
```

Where I have used `df %>% group_by(Letter)`.

I would like to write an if statement that says if the

```
max(number)-min(number) ==1
```

then the ratio for the max number that Letter will be `NA`.
In order words, if the two numbers are consecutive, I would like the Ratio for the higher number to be `NA`, and for the other one to remain the same. 
This is my expected output:

```
Letter Number Type        Ratio
A        10    Plant        6        
A        11    Person       N/A
B        9     Fungus       32
B        10    Bacteria     N/A
C        13    Bacteria     2
C        15    Bacteria     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` with `mutate`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(Letter) %>% 
   mutate(Ratio= ifelse(max(Number)-min(Number)==1 & 
                  Number==max(Number), NA_integer_, Ratio))
#  Letter Number     Type Ratio
#1      A     10    Plant     6
#2      A     11   Person    NA
#3      B      9   Fungus    32
#4      B     10 Bacteria    NA
#5      C     13 Bacteria     2
#6      C     15 Bacteria     3
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
indx <- setDT(df1)[, .I[(max(Number)-min(Number))==1 & 
                    Number==max(Number)] , by = Letter]$V1
df1[indx, Ratio:= NA_integer_]
```